# Stylesheet is not added when rendering whitelisted paths

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Can't figure out how to get my stylesheet to display for the homepage when I added WebApplicationConfig Class and AuthenticationFilter Class. My style she is located at resources/static/css. My current error says net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS...

I have tried adding the following to my WebApplicationConfig, but it didn't work either.

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/css/");

    }
```

This is my file structure. I am needing home.css in resources/static/css to be displayed on the home page.
[image]

This is my WebApplicationConfig that implements WebMvcConigurer.

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // Create spring-managed object to allow the app to access our filter
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationFilter();
    }

    // Register the filter with the Spring container
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authenticationFilter());
    }
}
```

This is my AuthenticationFilter Class that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationController authenticationController;

    private static final List<String> whitelist = Arrays.asList("/login", "/register", "/logout", "/", "/css");

    private static boolean isWhitelisted(String path) {
        for (String pathRoot : whitelist) {
            if (path.equals(pathRoot)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws IOException {

        if (isWhitelisted(request.getRequestURI())) {
            // returning true indicates that the request may proceed
            return true;
        }

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = authenticationController.getUserFromSession(session);

        // The user is logged in
        if (user != null) {
            return true;
        }

        // The user is NOT logged in
        response.sendRedirect("");
        return false;
    }

}
```